# Case stories that highlight the SOCIAL IMPACT of open data?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, data-request, nonprofit, survey

We are collecting stories that highlight the **SOCIAL** impact of open data or digital transparency initiatives, especially cases from the Global South. 
Would be great if you can help by providing data or open datasets about such stories.

Here's the [crowdsourcing spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jP6WIkEPczb8MBn6DNOU2PhKp9Prwe4HokqhUQVsxE0/edit?usp=sharing), and more details of our [research](http://sunlightfoundation.com/blog/2015/01/23/help-us-build-an-evidence-base-on-the-social-impact-of-open-data/).

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any question here. Please be aware that [Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum).